# Can we use Background is in <div> tag

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Can we use background in < div>, like we use in

```
<body background="image.jpg">
```

i dont want to use styling like this.

```
<div style="background:url(...);">
```

can we use

```
<div background="image.jpg">
```

because it seems that it doesnt work, is there another way?

edit

because i want to make images height responsive. and images are dynamic so i cant use style.css and i am using < div style="background:url(...);" right now but height doesnt seems to be changing as width changes

Comment: Why don't you want to do it in the only reasonable and possible way, which is CSS?

Comment: should use CSS3 and if we are in version 5 of HTML, where design provides style sheets

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen because i want to make images height responsive. and images are dynamic so i cant use style.css and i am using < div style="background:url(...);" right now but height doesnt seems to be changing as width changes.

Comment: So you're actually asking how to make the bg image keep its aspect ratio with CSS, not how to use a non-existent attribute. It always helps to ask the proper question and explain the situation.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div class="class"><img src="image link" /></div>

.class img {
    width: 50%;
}
```

its auto responsive

check this: https://jsfiddle.net/TiG3R/vjcg2utn/

Answer (score 0):

Sure, You can use there is no issue but preferable code is like below following

CSS

```
.img-bg{
background-size:100% 100%;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
display:block;
height:100%;
width:100%;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="img-bg" style="backgound:url('image/path.jpg')"></div>
```